# Restrict user to rename of file

Tags: android, android-sdcard, chmod

I'm downloading video from server and save to sdcard then i'm checking if the video file is exist it stops download again. If user rename of the file i can't able to check exist. How to restrict user to rename of downloaded video inside folder?

Comment: why don't you just save a list with the downloaded files in the shared preferences. If the file name exists there you shouldn't download it.

Comment: @mihail what on clear app data?

Comment: App ideas is download video from server and play from sdcard

Comment: so, if the user clears the app data, he will expect the videos to be gone also, am I right?